# Sliding Window but changing where next window begins

Tags: python, arrays, loops, sliding-window

I have the following code:

```
A = list(range(1, 200))
for i in range(len(A)):
    print(A[i : i+5 ])
```

Which produces the output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
...
```

For the above code, how would I change it to start each next array an additional 3 places? For example, the output would look like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
...
```

Comment: Pass start, end, and stepsize to range: `for i in range(0, len(A), 3):`

Comment: `for i in [0,4,5,6,...]:` - if you want arbitrary stepping, you will have to describe/generate it somehow yourself.

Comment: Are you sure your outputs are correct? `A[i : i+5 ]` in the first one shouldn't produce slices with 10 elements each, and in the second case, it looks like only the second iteration is offset by 3, then it's only offset by 1 again. Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = list(range(1, 200))
for i in range(len(A)):
   if i == 0:
      print(A[i : i+10 ])    
   a = i + 4
   print(A[a : a+10 ])
```

Comment: Instead of ```A = list(range(1, 200))```, why don't you do ```for i in range(1,200)```?